# Sed delete multiple lines after text match to the end

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Use sed to delete everything from Contact names to last *

```
Contact names

    *********************************************************************************
    CREATE DATABASE phpdb CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
    GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,DROP,ALTER,INDEX
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
    *********************************************************************************
```

I have so far

```
^Contact\ names.*
```

Comment: is the expected output would be empty?

Comment: Better gives expected output

Comment: Yes expected output would be empty

Comment: Try sed -r `'s/(?<=^Contact\ names).+//s'`

Comment: @sln sed won't support lookarounds.

Comment: @AvinashRaj9 - Is it primitive ?

Comment: When used in a bash script i get the error "sed: -i may not be used with stdin"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed -i.bak '/Contact names/,$d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
$ cat file
foobar1

Contact names

    *********************************************************************************
    CREATE DATABASE phpdb CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
    GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,DROP,ALTER,INDEX
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
    *********************************************************************************

foobar2
```

Code:

```
$ perl -0pe 's/^Contact names.*?\*{81}.*?\*{81}//sm' file
foobar1



foobar2
```